# How to create multiple divs around text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put some divs around span, I am having problems with getting the height and width of the text. I don't use box shadows as they will be used in an animation. Here is a link with a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuvWJ.jpg) of how I want it to look. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhjo7but/) is the code currently.

I tried multiple methods including having multiple spans which are the same, but I can't include the ::after code as that will make my code all weird and having a .mid and .max width, but that also messed up my ::after code and transitions.

```css
:root {
  --txt-color: #fff;
  --txt-box-bg: #424242;
  --main-bg: #000;
  --transparent: transparent;

  /* front page title text */
  --main-front-color: #e84118;
  --second-front-color: #fbc531;
  --third-front-color: #00a8ff;
}


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* Text */
.head-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.main-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono" monospace;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.light {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

/* Allgin */
.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* classes */
.front-page {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
}

.full-page {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* IDs */
#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;

  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;


  background-image: linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  transition: 1s all;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--main-front-color);
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
  z-index: 2;
}

#title-text::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: var(--txt-color);
  transition: 1s all;
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

#title-text:hover {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}

#title-text:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes stroke-rainbow {
  0% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
    #title-text::after {

    }
  }
  25% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: var(--third-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--third-front-color);
    background-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:400,400i|IBM+Plex+Sans:100,100i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Full page intro -->
    <div class="front-page full-page">
      <span id="title-text" class="center head-text">Hi</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool! What have you tried to accomplish this and what did it produce? Add any relevant code to your question to show your efforts.

Comment: @rpm first of all, I tried making several spans with the same text and info, but it wasn't working, most likely because I used an ::after code to make the code have a color transition effect, and I can't copy that because it make the text all messed up.I also tried have a min. and Max. width, but that interfered with my animation and ::after code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this effectively using flexbox. Create one container div with a series of nested divs with colored borders. Put your text in the centermost div.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="two">
      <div id="three">
        <div id="four">
          <div id="five">
            <div id="six">
              Hi!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#one {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

#two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}

#three {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
  padding: 20px;
}

#four {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

#five {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

#six {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT:** In retrospect, it would be cleaner to give each one of the numbered divs (e.g. #one, #two, etc.) a shared class of something like `.colored-box` in your HTML, then in your CSS use that class for all of the shared properties, so that you don't repeat your code.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one" class="colored-box">
    <div id="two" class="colored-box">
      <div id="three" class="colored-box">
        <div id="four" class="colored-box">
          <div id="five" class="colored-box">
            <div id="six" class="colored-box">
              Hi!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.colored-box {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 20px;
    }

#one {
      border: 2px solid yellow;
    }

#two {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
```